# Library workflow starts on upload, but not on save in the edit form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, document-library

I have a document library for pictures and I've created a SPD workflow tha should start every time items are changed or added: newly uploaded, edited metadata or uploaded againg (overwritten). The workflow shoud send an email about the change.

So when I upload a file and I click OK on the Upload page the workflow fires. Then the Edit page appears and I click Save but the workflow does not start. What I want is the opposite. The user should upload a picture, then he should edit the metadata in the edit form and when he clicks Save, then the workflow should start.

The list is with "Require content approval" set to "yes" and "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited" set to "no", if that's any help.

I don't undersand why the workflow would not start on Save. Plese tell me if I'm missing somthing. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the workflow kick off if the edited content gets approved?

Comment: yes, when the pucture gets approved the workflow starts and behaves properly.

Comment: Does the workflow complete in between upload and save? You can only have one instance running at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow is behaving as designed.  Workflows will not kick off until an item requiring approval is approved.  You will either need to remove the require approval requirement or train the users that the workflow will not kick off until the item is approved.

Comment: So a workflow will start on upload of a file, but not on Save in the edit form unil the item is approved. I find that  strange. Doesn't the upload operation change the approval status to pending. Also I can start the workflow manualy.